# Trouble connecting Xamarin.Forms to Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day. I'm having trouble on how am I going to show all the records I have created in my ASP.NET WEB API to Xamarin.Forms Application. I tried creating pre-defined list of Employee's Name and Department and it worked. But what I want to do is Create a Record in ASP.NET Web Application and make it appear to my mobile application. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I watch a video tutorial regarding this matter. Refer to this link if needed. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lir75oNAeiM&index=2&list=PLpbcUe4chE7-uGCH1S0-qeuCWOMa2Tmam)
Here's my code.

MainPageMain.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinDemo.Views.MainPageMain"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinDemo"
         BackgroundColor="Teal">

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
       HasUnevenRows="True">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                  Padding="12,6">
           <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
              FontSize="24"/>

           <Label Text="{Binding Department}"
              FontSize="18"
              Opacity="0.6"/>
         </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>


 </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
    {
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<Employee> _employeesList;

    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeesList; }
        set
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    }
}
```

EmployeesServices.cs

```
using Plugin.RestClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Services
{
public class EmployeesServices
{


     public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
     {
        RestClient<Employee> restClient = new RestClient<Employee>();

        var employeesList =  await restClient.GetAsync();

        return employeesList;

     }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's what I've tried. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: Does your webservice request complete successfully and return the List<Employee>?

Comment: @Jason Yes Sir I was able to return the List<Employee> but only in the browser and not in my mobile application?

Comment: Well, good, you know your service works.  You you need to figure out if your GetEmployeeAsync in your app works.  Narrowing down the point of failure is an essential part of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a helpful post about the correct way to do this:

http://arteksoftware.com/end-to-end-mvvm-with-xamarin/

If your records are not being displayed completely on your mobile app you can test your ASP web service using POSTMAN and double check if it is working correctly and successfully returning the correct data, then bind the List or Observable collection correctly on your View Model and then update the list/Observable Collection property properly in order to show the latest records.

Comment: @Jason yeah realised that at the end of writing the answer, nevertheless I have edited the answer.

Comment: @MarioGalván Sir I have tested my ASP web service using POSTMAN and it returned the correct data.Can you check Sir if there's something wrong with the codes I have posted?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista I do not see anything wrong on your code, have you tried to debug all the process step by step? Does EmployeesList has all the employees of your web service response? does you list have anything at all? it can be different issues: Bindings, The GetEmployeesAsync method, UI issue or If you expect the list will update itself once you insert a new record in your database then that is wrong, you have to update the UI also, for example: http://motzcod.es/post/113280718807/official-pull-to-refresh-in-xamarinforms-140

Comment: @MarioGalván As far as I know there will be no UI issue here because I use the INotifyPropertyChanged so whenever there will be changes it will be automatically updated. Is there any other way I can get all the data that has been created in ASP.NET web application to appear in my mobile application? Sorry sir I'm just a newbie here.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista the changes are not going to show automatically unless you update the list from the web API, some important links to get this done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857975/xamarin-form-update-listview-itemsource, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshListView, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38472/refresh-listview-after-deleting-list-item

Comment: @MarioGalván I think I'm getting to far from my question Sir. My main problem is how am I going to show all the records from the web application to my mobile app. Is there any other way I can do Sir? :(

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista you can go step by step, for example is the list view beeing rendered? Don't focus on the data just show mock up data in your list view if the listview is beeing showed then your problem may be the bindings or the data a quick example of how to create a list view with mock up data is:https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/

Comment: @MarioGalván Sir I was able to show the mock data that I created. But everytime I try to retrieve data from the CRUD of web application, it doesn't appear. Can you check my project Sir?

Comment: @MarioGalván Sir I think I'm having problem with the binding. But as what you've said, I don't have problem in my code right? Then what do you think is the cause? Sorry Sir.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista It can be different things, your binding context, the name of your properties inside your model and your view model, double check that your have a Name and Department inside your model, try to set the binding from code behind also.

Comment: @MarioGalván Sir can I chat you instead? I have many questions to ask. If  you don't mind, can you give me your email address?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista yes, it is 15mgm15 at gmail