# Update List<T> data Xamarin / C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have form which opens by click. Here I add users data to my `SelectMultipleBasePage`

```
async void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
ListofUsers = new ObservableCollection<Models.Users>();
var items = await App.Database.User.GetItemsAsync();

            foreach (var user in items)   
            {
                Settings.userList.Add(user);
            }
     multiPage = new SelectMultipleBasePage<Users>(items.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList())
{ Title = Users }
     await Navigation.PushAsync(multiPage);
        }
```

`SelectMultipleBasePage` content page looks like:

```
public class SelectMultipleBasePage<T> : ContentPage
        {

            public class WrappedSelection<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                public T Item { get; set; }              
            }
            public class WrappedItemSelectionTemplate : ViewCell
            {
                public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate() : base()
                {
                   Label Title = new Label() 
                   //and other fields
                  View = grid;                   
                }
            }
            public List<WrappedSelection<T>> WrappedItems = new List<WrappedSelection<T>>();
```

And here is `SelectMultipleBasePage` with `WrappedItems`  which I am trying to refresh to get new data.

```
 public SelectMultipleBasePage(List<T> items)
            {                    
                WrappedItems = items.Select(item => new WrappedSelection<T>() { Item = item, IsSelected = false }).ToList();
                ListView mainList = new ListView()
                {
                    ItemsSource = WrappedItems,
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WrappedItemSelectionTemplate)),
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
                };
```

How I can add or clear items on my page with `wrappeditems` correctly. There is no `mainlist.Itemsource.Add` or `mainlist.Itemsource.Clear` commands. I tried diferent ways but with no result. Hope for some advices.

```
 mainList.Refreshing += (sender, e) => {
                //...
            };
```

Comment: Hope below link solves your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857975/xamarin-form-update-listview-itemsource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to update the collection and reassign to the `ItemsSource` property or use data binding.

In the latter case, you will want to use an `ObservableCollection<T>`. Whenever the collection is updated, it will automatically update the `ListView` accordingly.